# Access data outside its method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, methods, segue, qr-code

I am having trouble with my swift code. The problem is that I need to have my prepareForSegue outside of the method, so the data inside the method cannot be used outside and in my prepareForSegue. How can I use the data outside so it will work in my prepareForSegue?

I am giving you all of my code, since it can be usefull all of it :-)

The error is marked with ////-- --//// down in the bottom of the code. It says: use of unresolved identifier "metadataObj".

```js
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel:UILabel!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?
$$$$$$$$ var metadataObj: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject?
    
    let supportedBarCodes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        
        do {
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
            
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedBarCodes
            
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            
            
            captureSession?.startRunning()
            
            
            view.bringSubviewToFront(messageLabel)
            
            
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()
            
            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView)
            }
            
        } catch {
            
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]?, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        
        
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects!.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
            messageLabel.text = "No barcode/QR code is detected"
            return
        }
        
        
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects![0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        
        
        if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj.type) {

            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
            
            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {            
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender: self)
                    
                }
            }  
        } 
    }
    
    
    
    if let metadataObj = metadataObj {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue" {
            if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
                sendToDetailViewController.viaSegue = metadataObj.stringValue
                
            }
        }
    }
}
    
}
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `metadataObj` is declared inside of `captureOutput()` function. You need to move the declaration outside, same place as you have your `captureSession` etc.

For example:

```
var metadataObj: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject?
```

Then you can use it in both `prepareForSegue` and `captureOutput()`. Check for nil before using in `prepareForSegue`:

```
if let metadataObj = metadataObj {
   // use metadataObj
}
```

Comment: now I have added your code to my post and also tried in xcode, but I still get an error. I actually got two now. In the `if let metadataObj = metadataObj {` it says that I should insert ; after if.... And it keeps saying that. I also still get an error here `sendToDetailViewController.viaSegue = metadataObj.stringValue` saying "Variable used within its own initial value"... Can't figure this out..

Comment: I also tried putting your if let metadataObj etc. etc. code just after the part where it says `if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView { }` and that eliminates the errors, but then I should delete override and it still does not change my label on the other viewcontroller :(

Comment: You created new `metadataObj`, but you also create another one in  `captureOutput`, you need to delete the "let" in `captureOutput`. You also have `prepareForSegue` wrapped in an `if` condition. This is not a valid code.